# How to close the contour of integration when there is a branch cut from -infinity to +infinity at a negative imaginary value?

Tags: physics, fourier-analysis

From some loop calculation in an EFT, I have found the Green's function containing this square root: $$G(\omega, k)\sim \sqrt{\frac{D k^2 \tau - (i+\tau \omega)^2}{(i+\tau \omega)^2(-D k^2 \tau +\omega \tau(2 i +\tau \omega))}}$$ I need to find $G(t,k)$. However, "InverseFourierTransform" cannot do this. Therefore, I restrict myself to the special case $k=0$: $$G(\omega, 0)\sim \sqrt{\frac{-1}{\omega \tau (2 i +\tau \omega)}}$$ Even in this case, "InverseFourierTransform" doesn't work. In particular, the "ComplexPlot"  shows that the analytical structure of $G(t,0)$ is a bit strange: there are two branch cuts, one starting from 0 to $-2i /\tau$, the other from $-i/\tau-\infty$ to $-i/\tau+\infty$. Now I want to understand how to close the integration contour in $$G(t,0)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}G(\omega,0)e^{-i\omega  t} d\omega$$
on the lower half-plane of complex $\omega$! The goal is to find some asymptotic expansion of $G(t,0)$ within the limit of $t>>\tau$ or $t<<\tau$.

If anyone could comment on this issue I would be grateful.

Comment: How about numerical integration over an analytic path across the real  axis with an indentation around the origin?

Comment: Is ref/ContourIntegrate in version 13.3 of any help?

Comment: Thanks @josh. Actually I mainly need to calculate the integral analytically. However, I think I will have to follow your idea when k is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks @jdp. Indeed I was not very familiar with this. I checked it out. This is actually a very useful document. Unfortunately, however, it fails to calculate my G(t,0) by setting z El {"LowerSemicircle"}. (z is the same as my omega)

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer, but before we can go further we need to clarify some points about your question. As you are using Fourier analysis am I correct that you are aiming to integrate along the imaginary axis and thus go from the frequency domain to the time domain? I also assume that omega is a real value along the imaginary axis -please confirm.

First we make a function for your expression. You have both omega and tor together so we can absorb them into a single parameter which I will call omega.

```
ClearAll[G, \[Omega]];
G[\[Omega]_] := Sqrt[-1/(\[Omega] (2 I  + \[Omega]))]
```

Now we can plot the absolute and argument values of the function

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[G[x + I y]]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 2}}, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}, 
 BoxRatios -> {3, 5, 2}]
```

[image]

The plot shows that there are singularities at 0 and -2 I as expected. The argument gives us a clue about the location of the branch cuts.

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Arg[G[x + I y]]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}}, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}, 
 BoxRatios -> {3, 5, 2}]
```

[image]

If you rotate the graphics you will see that Mathematica has put one branch cut from 0 to -2 I and another along -inf -2 I to + inf -2 I. This is also clear if you plot the contour plot.

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Arg[G[x + I y]]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}}, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}, 
 BoxRatios -> {3, 5, 2}, ContourShading -> False, 
 Contours -> Table[h, {h, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/100}], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

With these branch cuts we will need to do work with the four quadrants of the complex plane. The values obtained from the left half plane will correspond to time greater than zero and the values obtained from the right half plane for times less then zero. Were you expecting a response for time less than zero? Negative times? This suggests that your problem is non -causal events start before time is equal to zero.

I am stopping here hoping that is helpful and that the points raised can be clarified.

Comment: Thank you @Hugh. I actually found the first two plots above. Regarding your question in the first paragraph, yes, I want to move from frequency domain to time domain. The original integration is along the real frequency (omega) axis. To find the function at $t>0$, we need to close the contour on the LH of the complex omega plane. Here's my question; given the weird branch cut structure illustrated in your nice plots, how to close the contour? ! I guess I don't fully understand your point in the last paragraph; do you mean that "the special form of branch cut" has led the problem to be acausal?

Comment: Yes, to me the problem looks acausal. If there are singularities on the right half plane things happen for t < 0.  Technically your singularities are on the imaginary axis so you may be able to indent around them and let the indent go to zero. However, this would mean redefining the branch cut that is currently on the right half plane so that it goes off to the left. This may be possible but needs more thought.

Comment: Are you hoping that the inverse Fourier transform will be real? If so the function should have even and odd symmetry along the imaginary axis. The pole at -2 prevents symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a rigorous solution - just some formal manipulations which, however, can bring some value.
Formally, we can present the integral in the form
$$G(t,0)=i\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{\sqrt{\omega \tau(2i+\omega\tau)}}d\omega=\frac i{\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega t-s^2\omega\tau(2i+\omega\tau)}ds$$
Changing the order of integration and integrating with respect to $\omega$
$$=\frac i{\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty ds\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\tau^2s^2\big(\omega^2+2i\omega\frac{s^2\tau+t/2}{s^2\tau^2}-\frac{(s^2\tau+t/2)^2}{s^4\tau^4}\big)}e^{-\frac{(s^2\tau+t/2)^2}{s^2\tau^2}}d\omega$$
$$=\frac i{\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty ds\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\tau^2s^2(\omega+ib)^2}e^{-\frac{(s^2\tau+t/2)^2}{s^2\tau^2}}d\omega\,\,\Big(\text{where}\,b=\frac{s^2\tau+t/2}{s^2\tau^2}\Big)$$
$$=i\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(s^2+t/2\tau)^2}{s^2}}\frac{ds}{|s\tau|}\overset{s^2=x}{=}\frac i\tau \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{(x+t/2\tau)^2}x}\frac{dx}x$$
$$G(t,0)=\frac i\tau e^{-t/\tau}\int_0^\infty e^{-x-t/2\tau x}\frac{dx}x\tag{1}$$
Now we can consider the cases

$1.\quad\displaystyle \frac t\tau\gg1$. $\quad$ Making the substitution $x=\sqrt{\frac t{2\tau}}\,s$ and using the Laplace' method
$$G(t,0)=\frac {i}\tau e^{-t/\tau}\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt{\frac t{2\tau}}(s+1/s)}\frac{ds}s\sim\frac {i\sqrt\pi}\tau \left(\frac{2\tau}t\right)^{1/4}e^{-t/\tau}e^{-\sqrt{2t/\tau}}\tag{2}$$
$2.\quad\displaystyle \frac t\tau\ll1$. $\quad$ Making the substitution $x=\sqrt{\frac t{2\tau}}e^{-s}$ and denoting $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac t{2\tau}}\,(\,\ll1)$
$$G(t,0)=\frac i\tau e^{-2\alpha^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2\alpha\cosh s}ds\overset{\cosh s=x}{=}\frac {2i}\tau e^{-2\alpha^2}\int_1^\infty e^{-2\alpha x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
$$=\frac {2i}\tau e^{-2\alpha^2}e^{-2\alpha}\int_0^\infty e^{-2\alpha x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x\sqrt{x+2}}=\frac {4i}\tau e^{-2\alpha^2}e^{-2\alpha}\int_0^\infty e^{-2\alpha s^2}\frac{ds}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}$$
Integrating by part
$$=\frac {16i\alpha}\tau e^{-2\alpha^2-2\alpha}\int_0^\infty e^{-2\alpha s^2}\ln(s+\sqrt{s^2+1})\,s\,ds=\frac {8i\alpha}\tau e^{-2\alpha^2-2\alpha}\int_0^\infty e^{-2\alpha x}\ln(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+1})\,dx$$
$$=\frac {4i}\tau e^{-2\alpha^2-2\alpha}\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\ln\Big(\frac1{\sqrt{2\alpha}}\big(\sqrt s+\sqrt{s+2\alpha}\big)\Big)\,dx$$
Dropping the terms $\sim o(\alpha)$
$$G(t,0)\sim\frac {2i}\tau\left(\ln\frac1\alpha+\ln2-\gamma\right)\tag{3}$$

Comment: Thanks @Svyatoslav. See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/783704/how-to-interpret-a-greens-function-containing-a-branch-cut-from-infty-to